# Duplicating docker container for debugging

Tags: docker

I have a running docker container. I have done some useful works in the running docker container. I have done these works not part of dockerfile, i have done it inside the container.[Eg: I have installed ping inside the container, not from docker file]

Now, i got stuck at a place. I am not sure if i debug in the same container, i may loose the thing that i have done so far inside that container.

So i would like to create a duplicate copy of it with all the things available in that running container[like i don't want to build a container from image and repeat all the suucessful steps achieved in the running container and then start my debuggging. I don't want to re-install ping in my second container].

Totally, How can i duplicate a container? If not what are all the possibilities?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

1. Create a base image and run it

   ```
   docker run -it <base_image> /bin/bash
   ```
2. Make necessary changes

   ```
   yum install ping
   ```
3. Commit it with a new name

   ```
   docker commit <hash tag of running container> new_image
   ```

---

Now if you open new_image by running

```
docker run -it new_image /bin/bash
```

You can see `ping` is installed in it.

Open base_image and there is no `ping` installed in it.

Hope it answered your question.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: the relevant command here is `docker commit`; the rest is there to recreate the situation the OP ended up in.

Comment: As I see, this doesn't clone data from origin container to new one

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save your modifications, you can use `docker commit`, see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#commit and you can also save a container, http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#save

Comment: ok Fine. If i do a commit or save and then i do my debugging, can i revert back to my saved state. Shouldn't i use pull again since it is committed.

Comment: If you commit, you will tag it with another name, and of course you can go back to the saved statse (that is what commit is designed for). You will have another image, so you will have to pull it if you want to use it. Pull can be almost instant if you have a cache or a local registry.

Comment: Let me check this. I 'll tel you

Answer (score 2):

## currently broken again

below only works with version from around Dec 20 '17.  I have not yet looked into this after Jan 18.

`docker commit` is fine for saving file changes into a new image, but it will not preserve changes in memory, open processes etc. Contrary to the popular opinion, the latter is feasible with `docker checkpoint`. [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint/#usage) and [example](https://criu.org/Docker).

Note: right now, the `--checkpoint-dir` option is broken: [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34601), [pull](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/35694). That is why a workaround like `checkpoint_dir` (see code) is necessary here. This answer should probably be updated in a few weeks.

It is [not possible](https://criu.org/Docker#TTY) to checkpoint a TTY. This [might change](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/76) soon. However, you can attach a new TTY *after* the restoring process using [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

You [need to have criu installed](https://criu.org/Installation). After, first,

```shell
echo "{\"experimental\": true}" >> /etc/docker/daemon.json
systemctl restart docker
```

, then

```shell
#!/bin/bash

# tty (-t) not supported
docker run -i -d --name sleeper\
     busybox sh -c 'sleep 10000'

# Makes a snapshot and stops the container (except if --leave-running is active). --checkpoint-dir is broken.
docker checkpoint create sleeper cp
# sleeper container exited

# Create the clone
docker create -i --rm --name clone\
    busybox

# Start the clone
checkpoint_dir="/var/lib/docker/containers/$(docker ps -aq --no-trunc -f name=sleeper)/checkpoints"
docker start --checkpoint-dir=$checkpoint_dir --checkpoint=cp clone

# Attach new TTY
docker exec -it clone sh
```

Now in the tty, type `ps -e` and you will see the process which started in the `sleeper` container and now continues in the `clone`.

`checkpoint` makes a complete blueprint of the container to hard drive, exchangable between machines. This feature uses [criu](https://criu.org/Main_Page) and is experimental. Criu cannot [create a blueprint of X11](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu/issues/2#issuecomment-53390611) applications natively.

`pause` on the other hand only freezes the container internally. There is nothing you can do with a paused container other than unpause it.

Answer (score 1):

As of docker implementation 1.0.1 (Server /client API 1.12), there is only support for pause/resume operations.

But as far as snapshotting of processes (in commits + push) are concerned, these don't work (not supported, though I've not checked documentation)

In summary,
1) Preserving state of running processes is not possible!
2) All changes being made to file system (persistent storage) can be saved (and can be committed + pushed to repository).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container `my-cont` and you want to debug it, there is no need to install debugging tools inside it. What you can do instead is to use another container from a debug image e.g. `xyz_docker_img` then let it shares the same namespaces with `my-cont` container with extra capabilities you need for debugging.

```
$ docker run -it \
                --pid=container:my-cont 
                --net:container:my-cont
                --cap-add NET_RAW 
                --cap-add NET_ADMIN 
                --cap-add SYS_PTRACE
                xyz_docker_image bash
```