# Can I clone a paused Docker container?

Tags: docker

I can suspend the processes running inside a container with the `PAUSE` command. Is it possible to clone the Docker container whilst paused, so that it can be resumed (i.e. via the `UNPAUSE` command) several times in parallel?

The use case for this is a process which takes long time to start (i.e. ~20 seconds). Given that I want to have a pool of short-living Docker containers running that process in parallel, I would reduce start-up time for each container a lot if this was somehow possible.

Comment: I can imagine a whole bunch of use cases for this scenario, especially having backups of the container (in its memory state, opened applications and such) for testing, memory inspection and bug finding.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only clone the container's disk image, not any running processes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using `docker checkpoint` (criu). This does not have anything to do with `pause` though, it is a seperate docker command.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666776/3779853).