# How can I make multiple copies of a docker container WITH configuration data?

Tags: docker, data-persistence, docker-volume

I have a `docker` container with `JIRA` running in it.  I have successfully configured `JIRA` with the correct workflows/fields.  I now want to create a `docker` image of this so that I can propagate multiple copies of this configuration (yes, there's a licensing issue here, that's being addressed elsewhere).

I know to persist data I need to create a `data` `container`.  But I don't want all my instances to use this same data volume - I just want my image to contain that data.  But I'm not quite sure how to do this.

**My thoughts are as follows:**

1. Create a data volume associated with my `docker` container.
2. Configure everything
3. Docker commit (?)
4. On the new system create a new data volume
5. Load the image created in step 3

Is this going to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471224/duplicating-docker-container-for-debugging). 
The #id-old-container is the id that is returned when you run 'docker images'. However, make sure you dont 'exit' from the container. Instead [detach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process) from the container ( Ctrl-P then Ctrl-Q ),  execute the following command, and then attach to the container.

```
docker commit -m 'Commit Message' #id-old-container new-container-with-JIRA
```